# Can I configure a spray server in the source code?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm interested in applying some spray configuration settings at run time and manually setting the config in the code (maybe this isn't advisable, but in this particular case I'm writing a server that needs to have `relaxed-header-parsing` set to true since it will be accessed by ipv6 and I haven't found another way to allow a spray server to accept requests while being addressed via ipv6). Is there a way to do this? How?

Comment: Yes, each section in the config always corresponds to one case class in spray. If you post the exact use case I can post a link to the class. For the server set the `Http.Bind.settings` property.

Comment: Btw. the setting `relaxed-header-parsing` is now gone for a long time. spray now always parses all headers (old `on` behavior) and you can only control if it should warn if it cannot parse a header or not (see `illegal-header-warnings`). What error do you get?

Comment: Was having problems with link-local ipv6 addresses. It seems the problem was with `curl`, which wouldn't format the `Host` header correctly in the case of ipv6 link-local host addresses. I had to use telnet to send a proper ipv6-addressed request and spray worked. However, it appears most browsers do not support using link-local addressing because the interface cannot be supplied in the url, so I will have to use another approach.